# which objects can be dropped by DROP VIEW CASCADE

Tags: postgresql, view

When using `DROP VIEW xxx CASCADE`, are there any other objects, apart of other views, that could be dropped?

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-dropview.html) does not clarify it too much:

> **CASCADE**
>
> Automatically drop objects that depend on the view (such as other views),

Comment: perhaps a function that run the view. You can check what objects depend on the view, simply run "drop view xxx", and if there's any dependent object, it will complaint about it and list all dependent objects.

Comment: A bit more information is in the linked section: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-depend.html  I guess the easiest way to find out is to run `drop` _without_  cascade and read the error message (as suggested in the manual)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but there it doesn't explain what objects can depend on views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a huge number of object types which *could* be dropped, but very few which you're ever likely to encounter.

A view might be referenced directly by other views, materialised views, or rules. (References from within functions aren't tracked, so the `CASCADE` won't pick them up; they'll just fail at runtime.)

On top of that, every view `v` has an associated composite datatype `v` and array type `v[]`, which could be used as the type of a column in a table, or the arguments / return of a function, and the `CASCADE` will pick these up too.

This extends to *every* object definition containing some value expression, as it could potentially contain a cast to this type: column defaults, type defaults, trigger conditions, RLS policies, index expressions, and check constraints. They'll also be dropped if they reference the OIDs of the view (`'v'::regclass`) or the types (`'v'::regtype` and `'v[]'::regtype`).

And of course, from there it keeps cascading, so the list of object types which could be taken out by a `DROP VIEW` gets pretty long.

But aside from the case mentioned in the docs, I doubt you're doing any of these things; I'm not surprised that they decided not to elaborate...